# jquery, attaching objects (instead of string attribute) to an element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build DOM with jQuery and fill it with data that is received with AJAX (data type = json). I'd like to also store this data as an object, attached to a specific DOM element. Does jQuery provide any method for this? The reason I want to do it is because only part of data is initially displayed; other data might be needed later, depending on user actions.

I tried using `attr()`, but it stores a string "[object Object]" instead of an actual object:

```
var div = $('<div/>');
div.attr('foo', {bar: 'foobar'});
alert(div.attr('foo')); // gives "[object Object]"
alert(typeof div.attr('foo')); // gives "string"
alert(div.attr('foo').bar); // gives "undefined"
```

Another way to do this would be by "bypassing" jQuery (`div[0].foo = {bar: 'foobar'};`), though this seems to be a "dirty workaround", if jQuery happens to already support attaching objects.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for that purpose, like this:

```
div.data('foo', { bar: 'foobar' }); //sets it
var obj = div.data('foo'); //gets it
```

[You can see your example code working here just by changing `.attr()` to `.data()`](http://jsfiddle.net/cEw9P/):

```
var div = $('<div/>');
div.data('foo', {bar: 'foobar'});
alert(div.data('foo')); // gives "[object Object]"
alert(typeof div.data('foo')); // gives "object"
alert(div.data('foo').bar); // gives "foobar"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the **data** method of the jQuery object. This way you can attach custom data (JSON) to the respective DOM element. Here is sample code:

```
jQuery("div").data("key", /* JSON object */);
```

later you can get the associated data the following way:

```
var data = jQuery("div").data("key");
```