# Select background layer from dropdown in leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Iam making a leaflet map where I want to be able to select the background layer from a drop down menu from the navbar.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Bakgrunnkart
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="basemap-osm" value="OpenStreetMap_Mapnik">OSM</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="basemap-water-colour" value="Stamen_Watercolor">Water colour</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

I have added a value attribute in the  tags with the same name as the layers are defined as. Not sure if this is good practice of very "hacky?" still learning..

I want to add the selected layer to my basemaps layerGroup to display it on the map.

eg.

```
var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});


let basemaps = L.layerGroup()
.addLayer(OpenStreetMap_Mapnik) // default layer to show
.addTo(map);

$(".dropdown-item").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let selectedLayer = ($(this).attr("value"));
  console.log(selectedLayer);
  basemaps.clearLayers()
  basemaps.addLayer(selectedLayer);
});
```

But because '$(this).attr("value")' return a string instead of the actual layer variable I get a typeError..

Any idea how i can work around that? I am quite new to js so I pick up as I go along.. =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery, attaching objects (instead of string attribute) to an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781069/jquery-attaching-objects-instead-of-string-attribute-to-an-element)

Comment: Unless I think this backwards, my question is not about attaching an object to an element. What i want is to get (already hardcoded) the property of an element as variable instead of string.

Comment: You probably _do_ see how to achieve your objective backwards. You have plenty solutions, the linked post being the most versatile in a jQuery way. A plain JS solution would use a _dictionary_.

Comment: No sorry I dont understand. I have tried this layer = $(this).data('foo', {bar: 'OpenStreetMap_Mapnik'});
  obj = ($(this).data('foo'));
  console.log(typeof(obj['bar']));
That is still returning a string

Comment: replace the object `{bar…}` by… your Tile Layer **object**.

Answer (score 1):

i am sorry that i have posted here : i cannot comment since i do not have enough point .

- First : have you tried to put the prevent default in the end of your function? .

i think it may be a cause of your problem .

second :  Have you tried to mention the key for the value using
   attribute? like this :

```
$(this).attr("key","value");
```

or if u have multiple parameters

```
$(this).attr({
    key:"value",
    key2:"value"
    });
```

third: have you tried to use the function that use callbacks inside  :
like this :

```
$("body").on("click","Mention_a_parent_if_you_have dropdownitem",function(data){
var myItem = ($(this).closest('dropdown-item')).data();
myItem.attr("Key","value");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try as soon as I am back at my desk and let you know the result. Thanks

Comment: If i dont understand this wrong, all your suggestions will set the attrubute to the dropt down item. But the attribute is already set, i need to get it, but not as a string as my current code does. 
I have worked around it for now by using switch case to return the variable instead of the string. But I am hoping for a more fluent way to do it

Comment: you mean : you want to serialize your string into set of objects ?

Comment: if yes , please try to parse your string using Jquery Element with Json newtonsoft library like this :
'
function ConvertStringToObject(element){
stringy = element.d;
var array=  jQuery.ParseJSON(stringy);
alert("this will give you [object object]"+array);
//I hope that what you want to 
}'